# How does a large number of various "installed apps" affect your PC and overall PC performance?

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have recently gotten an "Adobe Creative Cloud" account. I am wanting to experiment with some of the apps, so I was thinking of downloading the entire set of apps for Creative Cloud and just start learning some, see what might, and might not benefit me as an IT guy.

I have a Windows 7 - 64 bit - Alienware MX17 that is about 2-3 years old. No issues with it ever, besides two times overheating/shutting down, where I had to send it to someone and have it cleaned, and thermal paste applied (twice in it's lifetime). Overall I get great performance, and no drag. I work and game on it "a lot".  I have 176 free out of 500, but a good bit of that are Comics.

Anyway, I installed Dreamweaver, Photoshop and a few others with no difference on performance. If I just go through and download them all, will it affect my overall performance when gaming or anything else, or does it not matter how much you have installed on it..as long as it's limited on what is running at a given time?  Thanks!

Comment: Installed applications unless they are running should affect your computer's performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does installing many programs really slow down Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/180424/does-installing-many-programs-really-slow-down-windows), [Installing too many applications on Windows. Is that possible?](http://superuser.com/questions/375588/installing-too-many-applications-on-windows-is-that-possible), [Does having more installed programs slow down a computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/330707/does-having-more-installed-programs-slow-down-a-computer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ramhound's comment really says it all.

Many large Windows applications (and some small ones) will install

- services
- scheduled tasks
- and things to run on system startup or login.

A common reason for these services is to allow the application to update itself, keep a system tray icon up, or even report on your usage of the application.  Having too many of these running can affect system performance.

CCleaner has a friendly interface to look at and disable programs that run on startup.
You can also check running services in Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.

Sysinternals' Autoruns is more complex to use (and you must exercise caution because you can take out critical Windows components if you are not careful), but lets you look at *everything* that runs when your computer starts up - including services.

Be careful if you look at this - some run-on-startup programs and many services are needed for proper operation of your system so make sure you investigate things before disabling.

Some applications may install drivers or other software that hooks into various operating system functions or COM components.  Antivirus or firewall software is a prime example of this - if you have real-time scanning enabled, a component of your antivirus software is running every time a file operation is performed.  This obviously affects performance.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for. Going to install these now, and then I will check to make sure all are disabled on startup, and there are no processes or services that run in the background.  Thanks!