Does installing Office 2024 slow down Windows 11 even if I don't use Office?
I use Microsoft Windows 11 24H2. I am considering installing Microsoft Office 2024. Does installing Office 2024 slow down Windows 11 even if I don't use Office?

This question has already been asked, in a more generic form, but the answers there apply here and answer your question: https://superuser.com/questions/180424/does-installing-many-programs-really-slow-down-windows


Does installing Office 2024 slow down Windows 11 even if I don't use Office?

It seems the answer is no:


I have never heard Office being responsible for system performance degradation, and I certainly have never experienced it myself, but that’s one individual’s experience and opinion on the matter. I also know nothing about your system specifications, not that it should matter, but Windows 11 24H2 running on supported hardware will run “better” than on unsupported hardware. Ramhound Commented14 mins ago 
As a general comment, having run Office products personally and professionally for decades, I cannot recall a situation where Office being installed was any sort of measurable performance hit, even once they went to the Click-To-Run and with the activation services and those processes. These never used more than a few MB of RAM and no CPU unless patches were installing. music2myear Commented5 mins ago
No, you may want to opt out of telemetry if there is any. cdubyab15/ on Reddit.


